# Get-PnpListItem HasUniqueRoleAssignments

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to retrieve list items that have unique role assignments from a list in SharePoint Online using `Get-PnpListItem`, is this possible?

Currently this property is empty when using `Get-PnpListItem`, I can iterate over the list items and use `Get-PnpProperty` to retrieve this property though I thought there might be a more efficient way.

I'm looking to get the same results as you would find from `_layouts/15/uniqperm.aspx` on a site.

Answer (score 2):

By list item object, it means passing the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem object. "HasUniqueRoleAssignments" can only return by "Get-PnPProperty".

I recommend you using Get-PnPProperty to retrieve permissions for items level: [Retrieve Permissions at folder and file level in Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221118/retrieve-permissions-at-folder-and-file-level-in-powershell)

Here is an example:

```
$item = Get-PnPListItem -List $lib -Id $id
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $item -Property RoleAssignments
```

You may need further details about the RoleAssignments property, to do so:

```
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $item.RoleAssignments -Property Groups
        foreach ($role in $item.RoleAssignments) {
            $result = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $role -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member
        }
```

Comment: Whilst that works I find it is much slower than doing the same thing in C# with CSOM, [see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53508076/is-there-any-efficient-method-to-query-unique-permission-list-items-under-the-li). I haven't been able to translate the lambda `ctx.Load(listItems, a => a.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(b => b.HasUniqueRoleAssignments))` in PowerShell with the PnP cmdlets.