# PnP PowerShell Get-PnPListItem access HasUniqueRoleAssignments Property

Tags: pnp-powershell

I'm using this `Get-PnPListItem` ([Get-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps)) function, which returns a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem` ([ListItem Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee539951%28v%3doffice.15%29))

Looking at the documentation of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem` ([ListItem Members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544534%28v%3doffice.15%29)) `ListItem`seems to have the Member variable `HasUniqueRoleAssignments`.

I'm not able to retrive this member variable using PnP PowerShell I'm just getting back nothing.

With the `Get-PnPList` command this can be fixed by putting `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` as an inclue like so: 
`$lists = Get-PnPList -Includes HasUniqueRoleAssignments`

With `Get-PnPListItem` it's not possible to do that since there is no `-Includes` option.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

PnP have option Get-PnPProp,for list item object, it means passing the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem object. "HasUniqueRoleAssignments" can only return by "Get-PnPProperty"

[Get-PnPProperty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221118/retrieve-permissions-at-folder-and-file-level-in-powershell)